# how to dynamically increase JDialog size in swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JDialog` and inside it am having a `JLabel` in which the contents are added dynamically. Initially I set the size of the `JDialog` and `JLabel` (both having same size), now if my contents in the `JLabel` exceeds the size of the `JDialog`, the content is not visible.

How can i dynamically change the size of the `JDialog` so that the size gets matched to the content with using layouts?

Comment: Layouts are very useful, I would suggest getting more comfortable with them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Invoke   `pack` after the jlabel content change.